# Defining generics from supertype at runtime when overriding methods in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, class-hierarchy

I have a class called `AbstractCollection<E>` and a subclass called `AbstractMap<K, V>`. The subclass is defined as `public abstract class AbstractMap<K, V> extends AbstractCollection<Pair<K, V>>`. A method called append in `AbstractCollection<E>` has the following signature `protected abstract int append(E element)`. But when I override this method in the AbstractMap class `public int append(Pair<K, V> pair)`, I get an error. None of the generics are wild-cards, since they are all specified when an instance of AbstractMap is created as K and V, and therefore I don't understand why this error pops up.

I also tried to let Eclipse override the method for me, but it writes the same signature as I did, and so the error is still there. `Right-click on code >> Source >> Override/Implement Methods...`

UPDATE
I've recreated the code that produce the error in the simplest form:

```
public abstract class AbstractCollection<E> {

    protected abstract int append(E element);
}

public abstract class AbstractMap<K, V> extends AbstractCollection<Pair<K, V>> {

    @Override
    public int append(Pair<K, V> pair) {  //error pops up here
        //... 
    }

    public static final class Pair<K, V> {

    }
}
```

I also tried this again on another version of Eclipse, and now it works, although the error flag still appears on the version I mainly use (Luna with java 8).

The error flag contains this message:

> The method append(AbstractMap.Pair) of type AbstractMap must override or implement a supertype method

Comment: Is it just _some_ error or is it a very specific error that will help us figure out what is wrong?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Are you sure you gave all the details needed? See http://ideone.com/vMamgs.

Comment: Can you be explicit about where those classes are located? Are they declared in their own file?

Comment: AbstractCollection and AbstractMap are two seperate files. Pair is defined in AbstractMap. Currently i've defined Pair in its own file, as this approach doesnt generate the error flag. I'm just curious to know why. @SotiriosDelimanolis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a problem with how Eclipse reports errors.

What it should have reported first is

```
public abstract class AbstractMap<K, V> extends AbstractCollection<Pair<K, V>> {
//                                                                 ^ undefined at this point
```

When declaring this class and its supertype, the type `Pair` isn't in lexical scope. You need to import it.

```
import com.example.AbstractMap.Pair;
```

or use its fully qualified name

```
public abstract class AbstractMap<K, V> extends AbstractCollection<com.example.AbstractMap.Pair<K, V>> {
```